# local language characters not displayed when I use #include file

Tags: html, asp-classic, server-side-includes

So the way I set up my website is users are redirected to the content page based on the QueryString value.

But the header stays the same.

Problem I am having is the local language characters.

They are not displayed in the content page even though meta-equiv is there when I check the source code.

What may be the problem here? How can I fix it?

Thanks a million..

```
<%
    Section = Request.QueryString("Section")

    If Section = "" then 
%>
<!-- #Include File="home/index.asp" -->
<%
    ElseIf Section = "home" then 
%>
<!-- #Include File="home/index.asp" -->
<%
    ElseIf Section = "friends" then 
%>
```

Comment: Was the original text entered as UTF-8? Are you declaring UTF-8 encoding on your page?

Comment: yes, I declare charset=windows-1254, charset=ISO-8859-9 and charset=UTF-8 in meta tags

Comment: You can only use one charset in a page.  You're better off sticking to UTF-8 unless you have a strong reason not to

Comment: it doesnt fix my issue whether I removed other charset tags. 
title of the table should be giriş here, but look how its displayed... [http://www.insead4sq.com/aslanyurekv2/inner.asp?Section=myaccount&SubSection=signin]

Comment: See the edit to my answer below

Comment: My motto: UTF-8 end-to-end or die!

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try

1. Open your page in Notepad and open the Save As box. What encoding is displayed?  If ANSI is selected then change it to UTF-8
2. Add <%@CODEPAGE="65001"%> at the top of your asp page

Edit - I tried adding the following as a comment but I couldn't format it

You're seeing giriÅŸ instead of giriş

Look at your source code - it contains

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9">    
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

it should contain

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: John, I tried as you suggested it, it doesnt fix it.
in fact the top menu is messed up too..

Comment: This is odd.  If you force the browser to use UTF-8 encoding (in IE right click in the page then choose encoding -> UTF-8) the correct Turkish words should appear, something in the page is overriding the charset declaration and switching the page to Windows/ISO endoding.

I've had similar problems before but the notepad save as UTF-8 method has usually solved it.  If you do use this method make sure you source code contains the correct Turkish rather than nonsense it gets turned into (eg <a href="inner.asp">BİLGİLERİM</a> rather than <a href="inner.asp">BÄ°LGÄ°LERÄ°M</a>) before you hit save.